# How do I fix this to show a variable number of menuitems?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this basic example, and I can see each menuitem by subscript, but the .map formation is failing.  The following is the code.  I am using a PDF to create this to help myself learn React.js, but the PDF is unclear.  Can I attach the PDF?

This is menu.js

```
import React from "react"
import MenuItem from "../MenuItem"
export default class Menu extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return (
 <div><h1>{this.props.menuName} Menu</h1>
 <MenuItem {...this.props.menuItems[0]}></MenuItem>
 <MenuItem {...this.props.menuItems[1]}></MenuItem>
 <MenuItem {...this.props.menuItems.map((item) => <p>item</p>)}></MenuItem>
 </div>
 )
 }
```

This is app.js

```
import "./App.css"
import MenuApp from "./components/MenuApp"
// let data = {...} (include the data array from above).
function App() {
    let menuData = [
    {
      menuName: "Dinner",
      menuItems: [
        {
          itemId: 1,
          itemPrice: "12",
          itemName: "Lasagne",
          itemDescription:
            "Meat and cheese layered between house-made pasta with bell peppers and onions.",
        },
                {
          itemId: 2,
          itemPrice: "10",
          itemName: "Cheese Ravioli",
          itemDescription: "Cheese-filled ravioli served with house red sauce.",
        },
        {
          itemId: 3,
          itemPrice: "14",
          itemName: "Chicken Parmesan",
          itemDescription:
            "Breaded chicken topped with marinara sauce and lots of cheese served over house made spaghetti.",
        },
        ]
    }]
  return (
   <div className="App">
       <MenuApp data={menuData}></MenuApp>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App
```

This is MenuApp.js

```
import "../../App.css"
import Menu from "../Menu"
function MenuApp() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Menu
        menuName="Dinner"
        menuItems={[
          {
            itemId: 1,
            itemPrice: "12",
            itemName: "Lasagne",
            itemDescription:
              "Meat and cheese layered between house-made pasta with bell peppers and onions.",
          },
         {
          itemId: 2,
          itemPrice: "10",
          itemName: "Cheese Ravioli",
          itemDescription: "Cheese-filled ravioli served with house red sauce.",
        },
        {
          itemId: 3,
          itemPrice: "14",
          itemName: "Chicken Parmesan",
          itemDescription:
            "Breaded chicken topped with marinara sauce and lots of cheese served over house made spaghetti.",
        },

        ]}
      ></Menu>
    </div>
  )
}
export default MenuApp
```

This is MenuItem.js

```
import React from "react"
export default class MenuItem extends React.Component {
 render() {
 return (
  <div>
 <span>${this.props.itemPrice}</span>
 <h2>{this.props.itemName}</h2>
 <p>{this.props.itemDescription}</p>
 <button>Add to Cart</button>
 </div>
 );
 }
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre] - what props are being passed and what exactly does "failing" mean? What did you _expect_ to happen? You seem to be trying to spread an array of elements as props, which makes very little sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to render a variable number of `<MenuItem />` components, in which case please try the below in `Menu.js`.

```js
import React from "react";
import MenuItem from "../MenuItem";

export default class Menu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>{this.props.menuName} Menu</h1>
        {this.props.menuItems.map((item) => (
          <MenuItem {...item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: SAM!!  You are the man!  It works.  Now, if I want to have more than one menu, what would I have to do?

Comment: I am glad that worked! Great question. (the below does not look great due to comment format -- each `<Menu />` is on a separate line)

You can do something like 
```
<Menu menuItems={items_for_menu_1} />
<Menu menuItems={items_for_menu_2} />
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: I have an array of Menus.  Can I use map here as well?

Comment: hey, one other thing I have a problem with is mixing the property and the html

Comment: so the menu item div tag is supposed to be  <div class="menu-item" id="menu-item-3">
where 3 is the menu item id.  But when I try to add it, it fails.  I tried

Comment: <div class="menu-item" id="menu-item-`{this.props.itemId}`">

Comment: @user9778277 great question, try using template literals :) (info: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp). for reference, your `div` would look something like this `<div class="menu-item" id={\`menu-item-${this.props.itemId}\`}>`

Comment: @user9778277 and to answer that question about an array of Menus, yes! you can use map as well

Answer (score 0):

There can be at least two problems here that are directly linked with what you might get.

1. Check that you are in fact passing `menuItems` as a property to `Menu` component, if it is undefined it will throw `TypeError: can't access property "map" of undefined`
2. Looking twice at the code, I noticed that you a de-structuring the result of
   `this.props.menuItems.map((item) => <p>item</p>)` which would result in an incorrect mapping.

Depending on your ECMAScript version, replacing this line as-is would do.

```js
{this.props.menuItems?.map((item) => <p>item</p>)}
```